# How to compare two objects and remove duplicate

Tags: javascript, typescript, array-splice

I am trying to compare two objects and remove duplicate value from first one by splicing. is there any best solution to achieve this

```
Record1 = [{"ID":"938"},{"ID":"939"}];

Record2 = [{"IDN":"938"},{"IDN":"939"}];

for (var k = 0; k < Record1.length; k++) {
    for (var l = 0; l < Record2.length; l++) {
        if (Record1[k].ID == Record2[l].IDN) {
            Record1.splice(k, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

console.log(''+ JSON.stringify(Record1));

Actual result> Record1 = [{"ID":"939"}];

Expected result> Record1 = [];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mutating `Record1` while you're iterating over it with a `for` loop, starting at index 0 and incrementing upwards - this means that some items will be missed. (eg, if you `break` at a `k` of 0, then the *new* item at index 0 after splicing will never be checked.) Iterate from the *end* of `Record1` instead, so that the `k` index that is spliced will always refer to the element at the proper index:

```js
Record1 = [{"ID":"938"},{"ID":"939"}];

Record2 = [{"IDN":"938"},{"IDN":"939"}];

for (var k = Record1.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    for (var l = 0; l < Record2.length; l++) {
        if (Record1[k].ID == Record2[l].IDN) {
            Record1.splice(k, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}

console.log(''+ JSON.stringify(Record1));
```

Or, even better, use a `Set` to reduce computational complexity and `filter` to create a new array:

```js
Record1 = [{"ID":"938"},{"ID":"939"}];
Record2 = [{"IDN":"938"},{"IDN":"939"}];

const IDNs = new Set(Record2.map(({ IDN }) => IDN));
const Record1WithoutDupes = Record1.filter(({ ID }) => !IDNs.has(ID));
console.log(Record1WithoutDupes);
```